# Positioning problem of a child element in css on Firefox and internet explorer

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to properly position the toggle eye of the password field using CSS.The problem is the positioning works well in google chrome but it's not working in firefox and ie.I tried to figure out the solution but being a beginner in web development I didn't get a solution. Please help me to figure out the solution.

**My HTML part**

```
        <div id="password">
            <label for="pwd">Password</label>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pass_word" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $pwd; ?>">
                <span class="icon"><i id="show-pwd" class="far fa-eye hide"></i></span>
                <span class="icon"><i id="hide-pwd" class="far fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div id="perr" class="err"><?php echo $pwderr; ?></div>
        </div>

        <div id="confirm-password">
            <label for="cnfpwd">Confirm Password</label>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="cnfpwd" name="cnf_pwd" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $cpwd; ?>">
                <span class="icon"><i id="show-cnfpwd" class="far fa-eye hide"></i></span>
                <span class="icon"><i id="hide-cnfpwd" class="far fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div id="cperr" class="err"><?php echo $cpwderr; ?></div>
        </div>
```

**My CSS part**

```
.confirm-password{
    position: relative;
}

.icon{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(-140%,40%,0);
    color: #555;
}
```

The first image shows how it looks in chrome and the second shows how it looks in firefox.

[image: Chrome]

[image: firefox]

Comment: Can you share your demo?

Comment: you mean the whole form?

Comment: yes with working condition

Comment: Okay i will share it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UL3OXoFmMENX2Iovn1rjntuzEjSKV_OX

Comment: Firebox(73.0.1) also working good tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div` has an ID of `confirm-password` but your CSS rule is for a class: `.confirm-password`. Change `.` to `#` and your `div` will now have `position: relative` assigned to it.